# Service + android:process "vs" IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, service, process, intentservice

As we know difference between Service and IntentService is that IntentService implicitly spawn worker thread whereas Service run on process main (UI) thread.

That is apparently showing what the difference between them.

But my question is that is there any difference between

**Service + android:process** "vs" **IntentService**

I mean to say if we launch Service in a separate process than still any difference between them except Service uses Process whereas IntentService uses Thread.

Comment: why do you want to run service in different process?

Comment: IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. While in service class you can handle those request synchronously, since it will be running on main thread, you may need to create separate thread inside service class.

Comment: @Pr38y If i spawn worker thread in Service then it will also transform in Asynchronous request handler is it not ?

Comment: no it won't. It will be synchronous means multiple thread can run at a time.

Comment: @Pr38y IntentService also spawn worker thread implicitly; and in case of Service we spawn worked thread explicitly then how r u saying IntentService is Asynchronous whereas Service is Synchronous. Sorry but i am not getting it ?

Comment: IntentService use one worker thread only to serve all the request. While If you are extending Service class it is upto you how many worker thread you want, you can create that's why it can serve synchronous requests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are completely misundertand the Concept of `Process` and `Thread`.

```
IntentService run in a diffrent Thread but run in main process.
```

For Every Application by default there is a only one process,in which all of your code will run including `Services`,`Activitys` And `IntentService` too.

When ever you start your `Service` in a new process then that `Service` has allocated with separate memory and heap area.It will not directly communicate with the main process.For communication purpose you need to use `AIDL`

For more info check this [Process and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: @AmitYadav have you read my answer??.if you start your Service in a diffrent process then you cant communicate with your Activitys which are in another process directly.

Comment: .@kalyan pvs that I agreed we have to use AIDL if I launch my Service in a separate process.